# How to relatively position Vuetify v-menu while triggering from v-model?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'd like to use a `v-menu` component in Vuetify to appear below a text field, but I need to be able to trigger the menu from a method. I can do that with `v-model` on the menu, but the menu appears at the top left corner of the screen. If I add `absolute :position-x="0" :position-y="0"` to the v-menu, I can change the position but it's still relative to the entire screen, not the parent div that it's declared in. When I look at the final HTML, it looks like the menu has been put as a child of the `v-app` container, which explains why it ends up where it does.

Is there some way I can position the menu relative to a page element while still triggering the menu from a method? Or, to put it another way, is it possible to position the menu relative to an element/component that has nothing to do with the menus activation?

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <v-text-field v-model="orgName" label="Organisation Name"></v-text-field>
  <v-menu v-model="showMenu">
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item v-for="(entry, i) in entries" :key="i">
        <v-list-item-title>{{ entry }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</div>
```